# Simplest way to combine jQuery promises?

Tags: jquery, promise

I have many situations where I need to accumulate multiple jQuery promises (animation or Ajax or "other"), but the simple test I tried did not wait for all of them to finish (*or for any of them*):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j7EL4/2/

```
function makePromises() {
    $('#box1').animate({
        left: 300
    }, 4000);
    $('#box2').animate({
        left: 300
    }, 1000);
    $('#box3').animate({
        left: 300
    }, 2000);
    $('#box4').animate({
        left: 300
    }, 3000);
    return $('.box').promise();
};

$.when.apply($, makePromises()).then(function(){
    $('.box').addClass("done");
});
```

Worst case, I would have expected it to wait for the first match before making all the boxes grey.

*Why is this not working as expected?*

### Update:

Now that I know jQuery correctly combines promises for multiple elements, I note you can also use an empty jQuery object's promise to provide an *empty promise*

e.g.

```
return $().promise();
```

This is great as an early return value (e.g. when no animations are started at all).

Comment: `$.when(makePromises())` http://jsfiddle.net/j7EL4/3/   **/** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @A. Wolff: Arrgh! So simple. The examples I saw used `apply` to manage a collection of promises. Was that wrong?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: `makePromise` returns a single promise, not an array. Hence you can't use `.apply` and using `$.when` is unnecessary either (for a single promise). Just do `makePromise().then(...)`.

Comment: Apologies to the down-voter(s) that found this question was not exciting enough for you. I have found the answers very educational :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I found the *question* educational. I had no idea you could do what you do at the end of `makePromises`. I had it in my mind that it would only work if the set you got the promise from was the *same* set you queued the actions on. jQuery was better than that (presumably collecting and doing `$.when` for us behind the scenes). Cool!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Presumably I can also use `$().promise()` as an *empty promise*, which would have been my next question (before the light came on) :)

Comment: To extend, you can possibly turn each box grey when they individually finish: http://jsfiddle.net/j7EL4/6/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Seems to work. The promise is already resolved when you get it, though (`$().promise().isResolved()` is `true`). I'd probably just use `$.Deferred`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this not working as expected?

Because `apply` accepts an *array* as its second argument, but you're passing it a `Promise`.

Since `$(".box").promise()` returns a promise that is resolved when all the queued actions are done, and isn't an array, you can't use it with `apply` like that.

All you need to do is use the result directly:

```
makePromises().then(/*...*/);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7EL4/5/)

(A. Wolff's code:

```
$.when(makePromises()).then(/*...*/);
```

...would also work, but is unnecessary indirection unless you have other promises you also need to combine this with.)

Comment: +1 for the `makePromises().then(/*...*/);` shortcut. The examples tend to skip little details like that.